# php mail() function not working to send an email

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wamp

I tried php mail fuction to send an email but its giving me the following warning and email not receiving

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set().Kindly help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Post your code to see your configuration (smtp, port, etc.).

Comment: Please provide more background info: what mail server are you working with, your mail params, etc.

Comment: windows localhost - do you have a mail server installed (i best you a $ you dont)

Comment: Windows does not have a mail server installed by default. The PHP `mail()` functions only sends mail to a configured mail server, it does not actually send mail. You will have to install a mail server or use something like the phpMailer library